# pause and resume jmeter execution

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am looking for an option to pause and resume JMeter execution (single/multiple threads).

```
1. Pausing and Resuming through command line 
2. From the Jmeter UI
3. By coding in some language in a sampler of Jmeter
4. Using a JMeter plugin
```

Any of the above methods is fine.

Any thoughts and solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going for [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

Despite word "constant" in its name, you can use i.e. JMeter Property via [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function as "Target Throughput" value.

1. Command-line: you can pass this property value via -J command-line argument like:

   - in JMeter define i.e. `throughput` property as: `${__P(throughput,)}`
   - "tell" property value to JMeter as `jmeter -Jthroughput=100 -n -t ....`
2. There is no way to do it from JMeter GUI without restarting the test. In general it is not recommended to run JMeter test in GUI mode.
3. You can also amend the property value during the runtime

   - for example from Beanshell Test Elements using the following script:

     ```
     props.put("throughput", "300");
     ```
   - using [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)

---

I'm pretty much sure that you'll receive a number of suggestions to use [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler from not very competent people who didn't bother to familiarize themselves with documentation which states:

> TargetCurrent Thread / All Threads **(ignored for Pause)**

So please don't waste your time on the Test Action sampler

Comment: I definitely missed that. I had used it for all threads but for stopping only. Thanks again for sharing. A good lesson learned :)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, could you give me any other references for Beanshell server apart from jmeter docs?

Comment: Here you go: [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell). Also check out [JMeter API JavaDocs](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the suggestion made by Oliver E. on user mailing list:

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201607.mbox/%3cCAK4Z_0AJ2c0_L==ByfgZ16FGgkyT5S9UnzboOaj3qc9PU94LSQ@mail.gmail.com%3e

Regarding your questions:

- 1/ follow 1 + 3 as per Dmitri Answers
- 2/ not possible yet :)
- 3/ Follow mailing list answer
- 4/ Not possible