# JMeter - Pause (and resume) execution on demand

Tags: jmeter, pause

I'm executing JMeter task for a few hours on a server,

I want to be able to pause execution for a few seconds/minutes and resume when server finish restarted

Is there a way to signal JMeter to pause and resume its execution?

I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499847/pause-and-resume-jmeter-execution), but it doesn't fit my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of current [JMeter version 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) there is no way to accomplish your "issue" with [built-in JMeter components](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html).

The easiest solution I can think if is: given you're restarting your server it should be not available for some time and when it becomes available - it should respond with a HTML page containing some text.

So you can "wait" for the server to be up and running as follows:

1. Add JSR223 Sampler to the appropriate place in the Test Plan where you need to "wait' for the server to be up and running
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
   import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

   SampleResult.setIgnore()

   def retry = true

   def requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(1000).setSocketTimeout(1000).build()
   def httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build()
   while (retry) {
       def httpGet = new HttpGet('http://jmeter.apache.org')
       try {
           def entity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity()
           if (EntityUtils.toString(entity).contains('Apache JMeter')) {
                 log.info('Application is up, proceeding')
               retry = false
           } else {
                 log.info('Application is still down, waiting for 5 seconds before retry')
               sleep(5000)
           }
       }
       catch (Throwable ex) {
           sleep(5000)
           ex.printStackTrace()
       }
   }
   ```
3. That's it, the code will try to open the web page and look for some text in it, if the page doesn't open and/or text is not present - it will wait for 5 seconds and retry

More information:

- [HttpClient Quick Start](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to send additional request before every request to server. I already know when to pause and I want to send pause/resume to JMeter execution

Comment: If you need to pause JMeter for some time (i.e. "sleep")  just use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) combination

Comment: But how can I call it by demand ? E.g. after 1 hour before server about to restart (time is unknown before execution)

Comment: If your question is about suspending/resuming any application, not specifically JMeter, in Linux you can use `kill -STOP ${JMETER_PID}` for suspend the process and `kill -CONT ${JMETER_PID}`  for resume. In Windows you can do something like `Invoke-WindowsApi "kernel32" ([bool]) "DebugActiveProcess" @([int]) @(JMETER_PID)`.